# Get ng-model value from quick-datepicker tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I use AngularJS with quick-datepicker library. The problem is I can't get the value of ng-model

```
<quick-datepicker type="text" name='start_date' 
ng-model="repariment.start_date" required></quick-datepicker>
```

The above code is inside a form.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    app.config(function(ngQuickDateDefaultsProvider) {
        return ngQuickDateDefaultsProvider.set({
        });
    });
    app.controller("perbaikanController", function($scope) {
        $scope.myDate = null
        $scope.setToToday = function() { $scope.myDate = new Date(); }
    });
</script>
```

When I submit the from and check the `$repariment.start_date`, it always return current datetime (maybe because null). At the backend (NodeJS), I can't get the value. How to make it work?

Comment: Maybe there should be a "repariment.start_date" defined in the controller scope ? ($scope.repariment.start_date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems here `$repariment.start_date` change it to `$scope.myDate` in HTML markup.

Fixed HTML:

```
<quick-datepicker type="text" name='start_date' ng-model="myDate" required></quick-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.myDate` in HTML markup

```
<quick-datepicker type="text" name='start_date' ng-model="myDate" required></quick-datepicker>
```

I think you are not using the correct scope variable

Answer (score 0):

Since you left out your `<ng-controller>` tag, I can't be sure -- but it sounds like you need to use the `controller as` form of the [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), e.g. in your HTML surrounding the control:

```
<div ng-controller="perbaikanController as repariment">
```

and in your controller, instead of `$scope`, you'd use `this` which will be bound to `repariment` thusly:

```
app.controller("perbaikanController", function() {
    this.myDate = null;
    this.setToToday = function() { this.myDate = new Date(); }
});
```

(That's, if I've understood what you're doing.)  It makes it so instead of using `$scope`, you use the bound variable in the template.

A more complete code sample would make it easier to answer for sure.

Hope it helps.

Steve